# Regex : Match first 15 characters but the matcher.start() should point to the 16th character

Tags: java, regex

Here I am using regex to catch first 15 characters to match, and while using substring I have to use (0,matcher.start()) only wherein I should get 15 only, kindly help me out.

```
   String test = "hello world this is example";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".{15}");

    //can't change the code below
    //can only make changes to pattern 


        Matcher m=p.matches(test);
        matcher.find(){
            String string = test.substring(0, m.start());
        }

    //here it is escaping the first 15 characters but I need them
    //the m.start() here is giving 0 but it should give 15
```

Comment: If you read the javadoc, you will see that `Matcher` has an `.end()` method.

Comment: Why not simply use `String string = test.substring(0, 15);` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I agree with @jlordo's comment: Use `String string = test.substring(0, 15);`

If you are forced to pass through the bottom code snippet which you marked as unchangeable, there is a workaround.
(Well that depends... If you are stuck with an unchangeable code snippet does not even compile... You're gonna have a bad time)

If you really need a regex that always returns 15 for `m.start()` you can use the [regex lookbehind concept](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
        String test = "hello world this is example";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=.{15}).");

        Matcher m=p.matcher(test);
        m.find();
        System.out.println(m.start());
```

Granted that the `test` input string is at least 16 characters long, this will always return 15 for `m.start()`.
The regex is supposed to be read as "Any character (the last .) preceded by (the (?<=) lookbehind operator) exactly 15 any characters (the .{15})".

`(?<=foo)` is a lookbehind operator specifying that whatever regex comes after must be preceded by "foo".
E.g. the regex: `(?<=foo)bar`
Will match the bar in: `foobar`
But not the bar in: `wunderbar`

Comment: Thanks Alderath for a real quick response, and for such an elaborate explaination...

Comment: Is there anyway other than lookaround because I've heard its a performance hit in java.

Comment: @chengYung If the input string is an arbitrary string of length greater or equal to 16, I am pretty sure that it cannot be done without lookbehind. Why? If you want 15 to be the returned index from matcher.start(), then the first match needs to occur at the 16th character in the input string. The only way in which it is possible to make conditions for what occurs before matcher.start() is lookbehind. If the input string always follows a particular format e.g. "16th character is always an @ sign" then you could search for the @ sign, but I'm guessing your situation is not that simple.

Comment: @chengYung I believe the only option if you want to avoid lookbehind is to change m.start() into m.end() as in GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR's answer, but from what I understand you cannot do that. Besides, if you only use the regex once (to match the 16th character), I don't imagine performance will be a problem. The regex engine will start searching from the beginning of the string and stop when it finds the 16 character. Even if the input string is large, only the beginning will be processed. Unless the code line is located in a narrow bottleneck of your program, I doubt it will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Matcher.end() instead of Matcher.start().

```
String test = "hello world this is example";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".{15}");
            Matcher m=p.matcher(test);
            if(m.find()){
                String string = test.substring(0, m.end());
                System.out.println(string);
            }
```

From API:

1. Matcher.start() ---> Returns the start index of the previous match.
2. Matcher.end()   ---> Returns the offset after the last character matched.

Comment: Thanks but 
I can make chages in pattern only I am not allowed to change anything in matcher as its working fine for other classes...